# How can I find the Average AGI given the Number of Returns with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, math, statistics

The data is available free from the IRS for income data by zip code for 2008.

A00100 is the Adjusted Gross Income (aka AGI), agi_class is the size of the adjusted gross income. This ranges from 1 to 7:

```
1 = 'Under $10,000'
2 = '$10,000 under $25,000'
3 = '$25,000 under $50,000'
4 = '$50,000 under $75,000'
5 = '$75,000 under $100,000'
6 = '$100,000 under $200,000'
7 = '$200,000 or more '
```

"Number of Returns" is the Number of tax returns for that agi_class.

```
mysql> select A00100,zipcode,agi_class,N1 as 'Number of Returns' from taxbyzip2008 where     zipcode="10021";
+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| A00100      | zipcode | agi_class | Number of Returns |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|     -954234 | 10021   |         1 |              3589 |
|    43243455 | 10021   |         2 |              2521 |
|   149940475 | 10021   |         3 |              3939 |
|   243853640 | 10021   |         4 |              3936 |
|   262995399 | 10021   |         5 |              3025 |
|   751195421 | 10021   |         6 |              5333 |
| 10677437299 | 10021   |         7 |              7477 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I need to come up with the **Average** Adjusted Gross Income for each zip code. How can I do this in MySQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select zipcode, 
       avg(A00100) as average_income
from taxbyzip2008 
group by zipcode
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that doesn't take into account the number of returns for each agi_class. Since they are not all equal wouldn't the number of returns for class 7 in this example with having 7477 returns have more weight in this than agi_class 2 with only 2521?

Comment: If you want the number of returns being concerned in the average calculation, then edit your question and add the way you want it to be calculated.

Comment: So, how is the average being calculated again?

Comment: Divide A00100 by number of returns for each class, 
compute the mean, median and standard deviation. 
For income data, the median is more important than the mean because it gives you the income at the 50th percentile.
The standard deviation gives you information about the extent of the variance for each agi class. 
The bigger the number, the bigger the variance. 
In effect, this means the greater the range of incomes for an agi class. How can this be done in MySQL or does it require computation be done in PHP?